# more wacky JavaScript shenanigans coming to mind

Tags: javascript, overriding, multiple-inheritance, instanceof

I just read through [Mike Koss on Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm). He briefly talks about sub-classing and touches on "an alternate sub-classing paradigm". After this example, Koss writes...

> Unfortunately, this technique does not
>   allow for the use of the `instanceof`
>   operator to test for membership of a
>   super-class. But, we have the added
>   benefit that we can derive from more
>   than one super class (multiple
>   inheritance)

... and it got me thinking. The idea of multiple inheritance seems cool! So I have two sets of questions:

1. Is the idea of multiple inheritance practical? Is it actually practiced? Any advantages or disadvantages?
2. How would I override the `instanceof` operator to extend its functionality to multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulated multi inheritance in javascript becomes a nightmare.

I wrote an entire custom class wrapper to allow dynamic multiple inheritance and I abandoned it after a month because it's just not worth it. The complexity grows out of hand.

Rather then using multiple inheritance you can extend your object with it's parents methods.

I recommend you stick to simple object constructors and the prototype rather then including external "classical OO" emulators. JavaScript is heavily focused on prototypical OO which is an object inheriting from another object rather then a class extending another class.

If you want multiple inheritance stick to object composition.

Be warned: This uses [`_`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for simplicity and brevity.

```
function Child() {
    var parent1 = new Parent1();
    var parent2 = new Parent2();
    // bind this to parent1 so it's got it's own internal scope
    _.bindAll(parent1);
    _.bindAll(parent2);
    // extend this with parent1 and parent2
    _.extend(this, parent1);
    _.extend(this, parent2);
}
```

Yes you lose `instanceof` checking. Deal with it.

More generically you can extend any object you want.

```
function extend(f, arr) {
    // return a new function to replace f.
    return function() {
        // store the correct this value
        var that = this;
        // call original f
        f.apply(this, arguments);
        // for each parent call it with the original this
        _.each(arr, function(v) {
            v.apply(that, arguments);
        });
        // add f to the parent array
        arr.push(f);
        // store the array on the object to use with instance_of
        this.__instance = arr;
    }
}

function instance_of(o, klass) {
    // is the klass included in the .__instance array  ?
    return _.include(o.__instance, klass);
}

function Child() {
    // do stuff
    this.method = function() { console.log("method"); return this;};
}

function Parent1() {
    this.foo = function() { console.log("foo"); return this; };
}

function Parent2() {
    this.bar = function() { console.log("bar"); return this;};
}

Child = extend(Child, [Parent1, Parent2]);
var c = new Child();
console.log(instance_of(c, Parent1)); // true
console.dir(c);
c.method().foo().bar();
```

This does rely on [`underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) to implement some nice abstractions to keep the sample code small. [*.extend*](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend), [.bindAll](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll).

See [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/De3NF/22/)

Comment: What is `_.bindAll()` and `_.extend()`? ... and sorry?

Comment: @Hristo I forgot to link underscore.

Comment: @Hristo the original code was broken. It now works. Check example.

Comment: @Raynos... awesome work! So did you just "override" `instanceof`, and by that I mean write your own version?

Comment: @Hristo I personally don't use instanceof to check inheritance. Actaully I rarely use inheritance at all.

Answer (score 1):

[John Resig's class structure](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) as well as many others do allow for instanceof checks.

You're not crazy for thinking about overriding instanceof (I actually commend you for the thought, it's something I'd do :)), but it's impossible.  instanceof isn't a function, it's a javascript keywords that's parsed out by the compiler and thus impossible to override.

As for multiple inheritance, nobody uses it in practice because it's impossible to keep track of.  What happens when two parent classes implement the same thing?  Which takes precedence?  How do you distinguish them from the child class?

Comment: But could you create your own function... something like `CustomInstanceOf`?

Comment: @Hristo Yes, why not. You'd have to implement your own tracking of what inherits what, most likely.